# How can I fix the bottom of the detail location when some row in the table is blank

Tags: rdlc

I am going to create the RDLC report that including the data table (16 rows/page) and the sign space at the bottom of the page.
Unfortunately, In case of the data are over 1 page and the last one has 3 rows, the detail that should be on the bottom of the page was shifted up as the picture below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/426vE.png)

Would be grateful if anyone give me any advice.

I try to set Can grow/ can shrink to False, but it does not work.